# I have Problem with GenericForeignKey in admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-admin

I have photo model with GenericForeignKey filed for 3 other model(movie, show, episode)
when i want to create a photo in admin i choose the content type but i can't use raw_id_fields on object_id

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    def get_photo_filename(instance, filename):
        content_type_name = instance.content_type.model
        return f"{content_type_name.lower()}s/{instance.content_object.name}/photo/{filename}"
    
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to={"model__in": ('show', 'movie', 'episode')})
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_photo_filename)
```

Is there any module that fix my problem?

Answer (score 0):

The `raw_id_fields` option is not available for `GenericForeignKey` fields in Django's admin interface by default.

This is because the `raw_id_fields` option requires a foreign key to be specified, but `GenericForeignKey` fields do not have a foreign key to a specific model.

You can use [`django-genericforeignkey`](https://pypi.org/project/django-genericforeignkey/), a third party package that provide similar functionality, by providing a custom widget for `GenericForeignKey` fields that allows us to use `raw_id_fields` for selecting the related object.

Install it using pip:

```
pip install django-genericforeignkey
```

After installing, modify your `PhotoAdmin` class in `admin.py` to use the `GenericForeignKeyRawIdWidget`, like so:

```py
from genericforeignkey.admin import GenericForeignKeyRawIdWidget

class PhotoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.GenericForeignKey: {'widget': GenericForeignKeyRawIdWidget},
    }
```

Comment: i don't want to use third party packages, is there any solution with tabular or something else?

Comment: @MMEEUR As already specified in first and second paragraph in Answer. Also you said in the question **Is there any module that fix my problem?**.

Comment: @MMEEUR Wait try to use `autocomplete_fields`, I dumped the code [here](https://www.codedump.xyz/py/ZA9yhXHAR6Mvu26q) at codedump.xyz see if it works for you :)

Comment: No its not working